# AWS ECS Installing same Docker version on ECS Instance via Chef vs via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, centos, chef-infra, amazon-ecs

I Install `docker-ce` via `chef` during the provision of my ECS instance via below recipe (the AMI of my instance does not include docker baked in):

```
yum_package 'docker-ce' do
    action :install
end
```

After running my ECS task to run a container on that instance it gives the below error:

> CannotCreateContainerError: API error (400): cgroup-parent for systemd
>   cgroup should be a valid slice named as "xxx.slice"

I then ssh to my AWS ECS instance and remove the chef installed docker via `yum remove docker-ce` and re-install it via `yum install docker-ce`. Now if I run my task from AWS ECS console it runs fine with no error.

I have checked the version of docker when installed via `chef` vs when installed manually and both are exactly the same.

There is not much out there about this error, anyone has any clues to why I get that error?

Comment: Weird one, possible yum metadata update needs to be done first?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Isn't metadata update handled by `chef`?

Comment: I have never used chef, so I am not aware of that. It is just something that you can try to confirm

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am not sure how to confirm it tbh. I only see inconsistency between `yum` CLI and `yum_package` in `chef`

Comment: See if you can add some `puts` statement in the `chef` `yum` plugin https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/7057cffcd9c9deab4e4e84423b9d9174bb2ae9ae/lib/chef/provider/package/yum.rb#L120